# text color for table of content

Tags: color

[![this][1]][1]Could anyone tell me how to get the text colour in the table of content of this project?
https://github.com/OI-Biostat/oi_biostat_text and to see the pdf click here https://github.com/OI-Biostat/oi_biostat_text/blob/master/oi_biostat_31jul2020.pdf

In my current thesis, I am using

```
 \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0, 128, 128}
\renewcommand*{\acsfont}[1]{\textcolor{myblue}{#1}}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=myblue,urlcolor=myblue,citecolor=myblue,}
\newcommand{\eqnumcolor}{\color{myblue}}
\let\mytagform@=\tagform@
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\color{myblue}(#1)}}
```

Thus everywhere I am getting teal colour which is fine, especially in the citations but the table of content looks very light in this colour. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colors in the table of contents are the colors of the links as defined.

In the project of the link above uses

```
 % _____ Online Version _____ %
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered, colorlinks = false, pdfborder = {0 0 0}, urlcolor = oiGB, colorlinks=true, linkcolor = oiGB, citecolor = oiGB, backref = true]{hyperref}
```

and `oiGB` defined as (too light)

```
\definecolor{oiGB}{rgb}{.5,.5,.5}
```

Using for the online version a darker color like

```
\definecolor{oiGx}{rgb}{.0,.23,.45}
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered, pdfborder = {0 0 0}, urlcolor = oiGx, colorlinks=true, linkcolor = oiGx, citecolor = oiGx, backref = true]{hyperref}
```

you will get

[image: x]

and

[image: y]

For your current thesis you might try

```
\definecolor{mylinks}{rgb}{0.0, 0.28, 0.67} 
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered, backref = true]{hyperref}    
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=mylinks,urlcolor=mylinks,citecolor=mylinks}
```

Comment: Sorry, I have understood your answer now, I am getting what I wanted but let say I would like to keep my citecolor as before I mean the one I was using, what should I do?

Comment: @Marso Use `citecolor = oiGB`  or any other color in the file `colorsV1.tex` in subdirectory `style` in `extraTeX`